# CASE statement returning duplicate rows. I only want 1 row per record

Tags: sql-server-2012, case, duplicates

The following CASE statement is returning 2 rows, 1 with the joindate = to the join date (cd.user_d1) if the person is a member and null if there is no join date on the record. How can i get the CASE statement to only return 1 row with the joindate field either null or with the member's join date?

I've searched and found solutions for other type fields with SUM, but nothing for date fields. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        c.master_customer_id ,
        c.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID ,
        c.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS ,
        c.FIRST_NAME ,
        c.INFORMAL_SALUTATION ,
        c.LAST_NAME ,
        c.LABEL_NAME ,
        c.PRIMARY_JOB_TITLE ,
        cad.company_name ,
        ca.ADDRESS_1 ,
        ca.ADDRESS_2 ,
        ca.ADDRESS_3 ,
        ca.ADDRESS_4 ,
        ca.CITY ,
        ca.STATE ,
        ca.POSTAL_CODE ,
        ca.COUNTRY_DESCR ,
        c.PRIMARY_URL ,
        c.BIRTH_DATE ,
        CASE WHEN cd.DEMOGRAPHIC_SUBCODE = 'join_date'
                  AND cd.user_d1 IS NOT NULL THEN cd.USER_D1
             ELSE NULL
        END AS JOINDATE ,
        CASE WHEN cc.comm_type_code = 'EMAIL'
                  AND cc.primary_flag <> 'Y' THEN cc.formatted_phone_address
        END AS secondary_email
FROM    customer c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CUS_DEMOGRAPHIC cd ON cd.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CUS_ADDRESS ca ON ca.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CUS_ADDRESS_DETAIL cad ON cad.CUS_ADDRESS_ID = ca.CUS_ADDRESS_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CUS_COMMUNICATION cc ON cc.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE   c.CUSTOMER_STATUS_CODE = 'active'
        AND c.ALLOW_EMAIL_FLAG = 'Y'
        AND cad.PRIORITY_SEQ = 0
        AND c.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS <> ' '
ORDER BY c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see the relevance of `CASE` to your question. Doesn't your question pertain more to your use of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: It may be, very new to this. We have many cd.demographic_subcodes so I don't want to pull that field into the select statement as it will return multiple rows. So I thought creating the joindate field based on the CASE criteria, and pulling it into the select statement would limit the rows to 1 per record. And I chose left outer because some of our customer records do not have address information, only email. So I thought this would ensure that all records from the customer table would pull regardless of whether or not they had address information.

Comment: I suspect there's a duplicate record somewhere, you're best bet is to break down the query, and check the tables for duplicate entries.